# Referencing an array element with the rename-item cmdlet

Tags: arrays, powershell, string-interpolation

I'm renaming localised .json files, which have the en-US suffix, with the correct localised suffix which are stored in array e.g. fr.json for French.
But I don't know how to use the array reference when using rename-item
Array is $array[$i][5] where i is the suffix for the language in question.

```
Get-ChildItem -filter *en-US.json -recurse | rename-item -newname {  $_.Name  -replace "^(.*?)en-US.json","`$1$array[$i][5]"  }
```

When I use double quotes, like above, I get the error:

> rename-item : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file >name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 >characters.

When I use '+' I get the error:

> Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. The -ireplace >operator allows only two elements to follow it, not 3.

Comment: Why is there a GRAVE ACCENT (backtick) before the DOLLAR SIGN in the replacement string?

Comment: ``"`$1$array[$i][5]"`` should be ``"`$1$($array[$i][5])"`` so the expression can be evaluated properly.

Comment: In short, as Santiago notes: Inside `"..."`, if you want to reference an expression that goes beyond a simple variable reference (e.g., `$var`), you need to enclose it in `$(...)` (e.g., `$($var[0])`). See the linked duplicate for details.